# PDO throws exception with a warning

Tags: php, pdo

I have successfully written my OOP class that extends PDO and everything seems to work as expected! However I am confused that if wrong db user/pass combination or name is provided, it throws Exception which is good but if "db host" is incorrect or invalid, it throws a warning with exception, why is that?

> [11-Dec-2013 14:37:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct():
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known in
>   /home/sdrop/public_html/includes/modules/monetarysoft/ttbs.php on line
>   15

Comment: Its because you're still providing a valid host name but there's no service running on it. the problem is the input is a string so almost all inputs for host name are valid ie: localhost or 127.0.0.1 or blah.blah.com etc etc so it can't flat out fail on the input it can only fail if there's no service running on the provided host.

Comment: @dave help yourself, the OP and the community: answer with an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: I never feel like my responses are answer quality so I almost always respond with comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved to answer on request:

Its because you're still providing a valid host name but there's no service running on it.

The problem is the input is a string so almost all inputs for host name are valid ie: localhost or 127.0.0.1 or blah.blah.com etc etc so it can't flat out fail on the input.

It can only fail if there's no service running on the provided host which is why it warns you that there's no service running and then throws the exception.

Comment: Is it your speculation on "valid host name" or a certain knowledge?

Comment: Almost certain knowledge since you can have a server host name in pretty much any format you like depending on if its internet based or local based or lan based like i have one internal one called just dashboard and one called database.dashboard neitehr of which are internet valid names but both are valid lan based hostnames.  Now in both cases pdo will throw up the op's error connecting to either if i stop mysqld on them if its running it works just fine.  As Robin stated though this is probably due to the internal domain resolution function getaddrinfo since that just resolves the input host

Comment: Ah. I see. means `intentionallynonexistent` domain is pretty "valid" to you. Unfortunately, it's only your private speculations, but other developers won't agree with you.

Comment: But intentionalnonexitant domain could potentially exist on a lan setting thats why pdo throws 2 errors one for hostname look up failure and one to warn that there's no service running on the provided host name.  if the domain exists but there's still no service running then it only throws the warn not exception plus warn

Comment: I appreciate your ability for devising interpretations but unfortunately, they are wrong.

Comment: Then instead of posting unconstructive comments please provide a detailed accurate and correct answer providing reasoning and explaination of your results so I can also learn from someone with such spectacular knowledge.

Comment: Please don't call my comments unconstructive. Thank you.

Comment: Well so far you've posted short cryptic comments without any valid logic/reasoning or even information backing up your claims on that basis I could respond to you in the same way so your interpretations and comments are wrong please substanciate your answers/comments. I would love to learn from a master

Comment: Don't turn it upside down. I don't make any claims. It was *you* making statements while I asked any proof for them. You didn't provide any - so, I take them as no more than quick musings you devised just in place based on your (wrong)  interpretation for the error message you see.

Comment: So there you go again making a sweeping claim without substantiation.  Please correct me since you know so much,  also please provide proof that my statements are wrong a simple link through to perhaps the core php documentation would suffice or perhaps an article you've written disproving my statements.  So far you're still commenting without being constructive.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have to bring any proof. It doesn't work this way. Stack overflow is not a gamble, where you just post some random answer and then ask others to correct it. To finish it: it is **your answer** which is not constructive. And you know it well.

Comment: You're right its not a gamble but if an answer is wrong as per stackoverflow guidelines when you downvote an answer "Please provide a reason for the downvote as a comment" you've still not provided a reason.  Then you can simply go on and teach me the correct way since you clearly *cough* know more than everyone else on the site.

Answer (score 2):

if you specify an invalid host name, let's say "ThisHostDoesPropablyNotExist.com" there's another internal function - namely *getaddrinfo* involved in checking the host name.

The warning means that PHP was unable to look up the host name in first place. If you just use the wrong combination, the server is reachable (so there are no problems in looking up the host address) and thus there is no error thrown by getaddrinfo.

greets,